# NodeJs, Mogoose: User model does not work when imported at top of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model `user.js`. Here is the basic definition.

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        trim: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I have used this model to query the database in my UserController, which is a class with static methods and it works fine. In my authenthication module file (`auth.js`) which I defined as an object with methods, `User.find()` or any other query method does not work when required at the top of the file. It returns- `TypeError: User.find is not a function`. Here is `auth.js`. When User is required within `auth.verifyToken` method, `User.find()` works.

```
const auth = {
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const errorHandler = require('./../utils/errorHandler');
const responseHandler = require('../utils/responseHandler');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { promisify } = require('util')
const User = require('../models/user/user');
dotenv.config()

const auth = {

    async verifyToken(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const access = req.headers.authorization;
            let token;
            if (access && access.startsWith('Bearer')) {
                let bearerToken = access.split(' ');
                token = bearerToken[1];

            } else if (req.cookies && req.cookies.jwt) {
                token = req.cookies.jwt;
            }

            if (!token) return errorHandler(401, 'Unauthorised. Please login with your details');
           
            const decodedToken = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, SECRET);
            //const User = require('../models/user/user');// User model doesn't work when imported at the top.
            console.log(User) //This logs an empty object, {}, on the command line
            const currentUser = await User.findById(decodedToken._id);

            if (!currentUser) return errorHandler(401, `This user no longer has an account on this platform.`);
            req.user = currentUser;
            return next();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            next(error);
        }
    }
}
```

In `auth.js` VS Code recognizes User as a type of Model document, but `console.log(User)` returns an empty object. I run windows 10 by the way.

Comment: I think you are using it before connecting to the database.

Comment: But it works in other files.